# Cardinality of intersection of finite collection of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S = \{A, B, ..., N\}$ be a finite collection of subsets of a finite set $G$, is there a general formula for the cardinality of $\bigcap_{X \in S} X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $$\bigcap_{X\in S}X=(\bigcup_{X\in S} X^c)^c$$ where $c$ is the complement with respect to $G$.

Use $$|(\bigcup_{X\in S} X^c)^c|=|G|-|(\bigcup_{X\in S} X^c)|$$

and the fact that we have a formula for the cardinality of the union, $$|(\bigcup_{X\in S} X^c)|.$$